# How do I clear the screen command history scroll-back?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

How do I clear the screen command history scroll-back? 
For instance, delete this -> ctrl-a : at "#" stuff "something.dumb"

I'm not talking about BASH history either.

Things I have tried->

- `history -c` won't work.
- scrolling up and trying to delete it won't work.

Comment: Please make it more explicit in your question (if I correctly assume by the tags) that you are inside the utility named "screen" and your question refers to this particular utility's command history. Your question sounds like "screen" is just a generic word you use meaning "window" or "display".

Comment: Have you tried `C-a =       (removebuf)   Removes the file used by C-a < and C-a >`

Answer (score 0):

I've this solution(?):

```
$ printf "\n%.0s" {1..100000}
```

**PS:** bigger upper bound is safer!